# Tabindexes are not working with child form

Tags: c#

I have developed a C# Windows Forms Application with .NET 4.5.2
in this application I use entity framework for database access and then I have a TabControl, where I use code to add TabPages. Each TabPage has a single control, which is another Windows Form. This works great, but one usability issue I have is that it does not follow the TabIndexes.
The inserted form works fine on its own and when being used inside of an MDIContaioner, but in the TabControl it jumps outside the tab.
In the main form I have the tabcontrol where I dynmaically insert one or more tabs with Windows Forms inside them as the only control.
Outside the TabControl I have two buttons.
Inside the form I have textbox1 and textbox2, with tabindex in the same order.
When I click in textbox1 and write something, I would expect it to jump to textbox2, but instead it jumps outside the tabcontrol and selects the first button instead.
Does anyone have a suggestion for how to fix this?

Comment: Why would you place a windows form on a tab control?? Have you ever heard of `UserControl`?

Comment: Why are you hosting windows forms in a tab control? Maybe you want to use a user control instead?

Comment: @Luaan Haha, beat you by 2 seconds :-D

Comment: I have heard of a user control, but did not think that it would solve the issue. I will give it a try.

Comment: Converting to a user control actually solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was converted from a WinForms to a UserControl and that solved the issue